# Is it possible to get specific user's live videos from Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, live-streaming, live-video

Suppose that I can fetch the `user_id` of some specific facebook user, is it possible to get this user's public live videos through Graph API even we are not friend?

use the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=%7Buser-id%7D%2Flive_videos&version=v2.7) provided by facebook to try to fetch some specific user's live videos listing and get nothing. Do I need some specific permissions to get it work or it is not possible to get this kind of information if this user is not a friend of you?

Answer (score 0):

You will definitely not be able to get anything from a user who did not authorize your App. If he authorized your App with the appropriate permissions, you may just use `/me/live_videos` with his User Access Token.

Comment: I added my account and my friends' as the developer Role in Roles panel of our app. We both granted all permissions available on the list of User Access Token from the Graph API Explorer tool. Now, when I called `{my_friends_user_id}/live_videos`  from Graph API Explorer, we always get the following return json:

    {
         "data": [
        ]
    }

have any ideas?

Comment: then there is no video, as it seems. could also be that it only works for pages though.